Wordpress placeholder input not synced with contrast on accessibility plugin
I have add wordpress plugin for Accessibility
One Click Accessibility
Why the plugin is not works on placeholders?
<input type="text" class="input-box" autocomplete="off" id="test" name="test" placeholder="text not works with plugin?" readonly="">


Thank you in advance!

Hey you can reach out plugins support

Yes, on Github, no idea until now

this plugin add css class on body then you can try this in the custom css code of the theme :
.pojo-a11y-high-contrast ::placeholder
{
    opacity : 1;
}


Where in the custom css code it should be added?
On the input element level? as this code not affect spesific on the input element isn't it?

It possible it's bug on this plugin that is not implemented the "::placeholder" handling?
